# Embed Vue.js app in Asp.Net MVC site

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, vue.js

I have two applications running separately. An application in ASP.NET MVC (ex: localhost:8082) and another application in Vue.JS (localhost:8080). For legacy reasons, I have embedded this app inside an IFRAME.

Is there another way to do this without using an iframe?

Something like this?

**Market.cshtml** (MVC site running on port 8082)

```
<div class="bg">
  <div id="app"></div>
</div>

<script>
  // vue app running on port 8080
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App }
  })

</script>
```

Comment: Vue at the end of the day is simply HTML, JS, and CSS. ASP.NET MVC can serve those. So sure, you can combine them. You'll just need to come up with a process for doing so.

Comment: For bureaucratic reasons I can not put the two applications in the same place and for this reason I'm looking for a way to keep them separate.